# Form not submitting after failing custom validation rule once

Tags: php, forms, validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

So I have a cakePHP (2.4.6) form and I'm trying to make a typical user registration form, with a second password field. I wrote a custom rule to check if the password fields' values match.

The first time I submit the form, the validation works, but after once with validation failure, the form refuses to submit again. Anyone has any idea why? This keeps happening with any form that has custom validation rules...

Here's the model for reference:

```
class User extends AppModel {

    var $primaryKey = 'username';
    public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'between' => array(
                'rule' => array('between', 8, 20),
                'message' => 'Usernames must be 8-20 characters long.',
            ),
            'reg' => array(
                'rule' => '/^[\w]{8,20}$/',
                'message' => 'Valid characters: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _'
            ),
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'between' => array(
                'rule' => array('between', 8, 20),
                'message' => 'Passwords must be 8-20 characters long.',
            ),
            'reg' => array(
                'rule' => '/^[\w\.\-]{8,20}$/',
                'message' => 'Valid characters: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _, -, .'
            ),
        ),
        're_password' => array(
            'same' => array(
                'rule' => array('same', 'password'),
                'message' => 'Passwords do not match!',
            )
        ),
    );

    public function same($first, $second) {
        $val = '';
        foreach($first as $k=>$v) {
            $val = $v;
        }
        return $this->data[$this->$second] == $val;
    }
}
```

Controller `add()` function:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        pr($this->request->data);
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'home'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}
```

The first submission works fine:
[first submission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf3QT.png)

But after I get the validation errors, whether I change the input values to have no errors or not, clicking submit does nothing - the page just refreshes with whatever values are in the input fields, like so:
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEhBr.png)

No flash message, no validation error message, nothing.
(Sorry, no reputation, can't post images..)

Comment: And by "_refuses to submit_" you mean...? Your browser doesn't send any data or what exactly is the problem? Or are you receiving errors? What does your view look like? What does the generated HTML look like? And what have you tried so far to debug the problem? ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly!

Comment: try to debug the result of form submit, in ur controller, when u check `if($this->request->is('post'))` or `if(!empty($this->request->data))` after that, put `debug($this->request->data)`, see what is the output

Comment: What code is actually in the Controller?  Maybe it's submitting just fine for all we know.

Comment: @hashmode - the first debug works, the second doesn't appear either...

Comment: @Dave - the function is very basic, didn't make many changes. added it to the question anyway.

Comment: Some code or bit of info is missing. Don't see any reason what you've posted would have that issue.

Comment: @Dave I haven't changed anything else though, and this happens with every project as long as there are custom validation rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your post with post,put like

```
    public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is(array('post','put'))) {
        pr($this->request->data);
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'home'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}
```